# IE7 Gets "Red X" when using jQuery Hover

Tags: jquery, image, internet-explorer-7, src

I am using a preview script via http://cssglobe.com/lab/tooltip/03/

The problem is that when I use SRC tag in this script - I get a big fat red X - in IE7 BEFORE the image is rendered. Once the image appears - all looks ok.

Is there anyway to "hide" this before its loaded or something ? Love an help anyone can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the red "X" the placeholder for an image that cannot be found. If so try pre-loading the image or using a sprite so that it does not have to do an HTTP request on the tool tip.

Comment: thanks for the response ;) basically, when you rollover the link the image doesn't appear to have loaded yet - so I get an X - then it appears and looks fine. no other browser does this ?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot? It seems to be just a loading issue. I would pre-load those images if possible or use a loading screen if it is dynamic data. There are a lot of jQuery tooltip plugins, so look around it this one can't handle it.